# Can't figure out a function to return a reference to a given type stored in RefCell<Box<Any>>

Tags: rust

Most of this is boilerplate, provided as a compilable example. Scroll down.

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::any::{Any, AnyRefExt};

struct Shared {
    example: int,
}

struct Widget {
    parent: Option<Weak<Box<Widget>>>,
    specific: RefCell<Box<Any>>,
    shared: RefCell<Shared>,
}

impl Widget {
    fn new(specific: Box<Any>, 
           parent: Option<Rc<Box<Widget>>>) -> Rc<Box<Widget>> { 
        let parent_option = match parent {
            Some(parent) => Some(parent.downgrade()),
            None => None,
        };
        let shared = Shared{pos: 10};
        Rc::new(box Widget{
            parent: parent_option,
            specific: RefCell::new(specific),
            shared: RefCell::new(shared)})
    }
}

struct Woo {
    foo: int,
}

impl Woo {
    fn new() -> Box<Any> {
        box Woo{foo: 10} as Box<Any>
    }
}

fn main() {
    let widget = Widget::new(Woo::new(), None);

    {
        // This is a lot of work...
        let cell_borrow = widget.specific.borrow();
        let woo = cell_borrow.downcast_ref::<Woo>().unwrap();
        println!("{}", woo.foo);
    }

    // Can the above be made into a function?
    // let woo = widget.get_specific::<Woo>();
}
```

I'm learning Rust and trying to figure out some workable way of doing a widget hierarchy. The above basically does what I need, but it is a bit cumbersome. Especially vexing is the fact that I have to use two statements to convert the inner widget (`specific` member of `Widget`). I tried several ways of writing a function that does it all, but the amount of reference and lifetime wizardry is just beyond me.

Can it be done? **Can the commented out method at the bottom of my example code be made into reality?**

Comments regarding better ways of doing this entire thing are appreciated, but put it in the comments section (or create a new question and link it)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll just present a working simplified and more idiomatic version of your code and then explain all the changed I made there:

```
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};
use std::any::{Any, AnyRefExt};

struct Shared {
    example: int,
}

struct Widget {
    parent: Option<Weak<Widget>>,
    specific: Box<Any>,
    shared: Shared,
}

impl Widget {
    fn new(specific: Box<Any>, parent: Option<Rc<Widget>>) -> Widget { 
        let parent_option = match parent {
            Some(parent) => Some(parent.downgrade()),
            None => None,
        };
        let shared = Shared { example: 10 };
        Widget{
            parent: parent_option,
            specific: specific,
            shared: shared
        }
    }

    fn get_specific<T: 'static>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        self.specific.downcast_ref::<T>()
    }
}

struct Woo {
    foo: int,
}

impl Woo {
    fn new() -> Woo {
        Woo { foo: 10 }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let widget = Widget::new(box Woo::new() as Box<Any>, None);

    let specific = widget.get_specific::<Woo>().unwrap();
    println!("{}", specific.foo);
}
```

First of all, there are needless `RefCell`s inside your structure. `RefCell`s are needed very rarely - only when you need to mutate internal state of an object using only `&` reference (instead of `&mut`). This is useful tool for implementing abstractions, but it is almost never needed in application code. Because it is not clear from your code that you *really* need it, I assume that it was used mistakingly and can be removed.

Next, `Rc<Box<Something>>` when `Something` is a struct (like in your case where `Something` = `Widget`) is redundant. Putting an owned box into a reference-counted box is just an unnecessary double indirection and allocation. Plain `Rc<Widget>` is the correct way to express this thing. When dynamically sized types land, it will be also true for trait objects.

Finally, you should try to always return unboxed values. Returning `Rc<Box<Widget>>` (or even `Rc<Widget>`) is unnecessary limiting for the callers of your code. You can go from `Widget` to `Rc<Widget>` easily, but not the other way around. Rust optimizes by-value returns automatically; if your callers need `Rc<Widget>` they can box the return value themselves:

```
let rc_w = box(RC) Widget::new(...);
```

Same thing is also true for `Box<Any>` returned by `Woo::new()`.

You can see that in the absence of `RefCell`s your `get_specific()` method can be implemented very easily. However, you really can't do it with `RefCell` because `RefCell` uses RAII for dynamic borrow checks, so you can't return a reference to its internals from a method. You'll have to return `core::cell::Ref`s, and your callers will need to `downcast_ref()` themselves. This is just another reason to use `RefCell`s sparingly.

Comment: This is the kind of quality answer that makes SO worthwhile. It brought a lot of clarity to my still budding understanding of Rust. Still there is a question of mutability. If I understand correctly, a Widget wrapped in `Rc` can only be mutated by using `rc::get_mut`. In my test, and to my surprise, even a `Weak` reference cause `rc::get_mut` to fail. This basically means any `Rc` wrapped value is immutable - no point of having singular values wrapped in `Rc`. The purpose of the `Widget` hierarchy is to abstract access to mutable `shared` and `specific` states of a widget. So, RefCell?

Comment: @porgarmingduod, yes, indeed. If you need to hold mutable state in `Rc`, you need to use `Rc<RefCell<T>>`, so your `Widget` would contain `Weak<RefCell<T>>`.