# How to get a mutable reference to an arbitrary element in a Rc<RefCell<T>> tree?

Tags: rust

I have a tree-like structure like the following:

```
use std::{cell::RefCell, collections::HashMap, rc::Rc};

struct Node<T> {
    vals: HashMap<String, T>,
    parent: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>,
}
```

This is a chained hash map: each node contains a hash map and an (optional, as the root of the tree has no parent) shared pointer to its parent. Multiple children can share the same parent.

If I want to get a clone of a value out of this chained hash map, I use recursion to walk up the tree, like so:

```
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn get(&self, name: &str) -> Option<T> {
        self.vals
            .get(name)
            .cloned()
            .or_else(|| self.parent.as_ref().and_then(|p| p.borrow().get(name)))
    }
}
```

However, I need a mutable reference to an element contained in this tree. Since I cannot return a 'standard' mutable reference to an element, due to it being contained in a `RefCell,` I thought about using `RefMut` and the `RefMut::map` function to obtain one, like so:

```
use std::cell::RefMut;

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn get_mut<'a>(node: RefMut<'a, Node<T>>, name: &str) -> Option<RefMut<'a, T>> {
        if node.vals.contains_key(name) {
            Some(RefMut::map(node, |n| n.vals.get_mut(name).unwrap()))
        } else {
            node.parent.and_then(|p| Node::get_mut(p.borrow_mut(), name))
        }
    }
}
```

This does not compile: the return value references its child node (due to it being also dependent on its child's borrow), and the `RefMut` pointing to the child goes out of scope at function exit:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing function parameter `p`
  --> src/lib.rs:16:31
   |
16 |                 .and_then(|p| Node::get_mut(p.borrow_mut(), name))
   |                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                               |             |
   |                               |             `p` is borrowed here
   |                               returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:15:13
   |
15 |             node.parent
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

I do not understand how I could go about getting something deferenceable out of this tree. I assume I might need a sort of "`RefMut` chain" in order to extend the lifetime of the child node `RefMut`, but wouldn't that also create multiple mutable references to (components of) the same `Node`?

Alternatively, is there a way to get some sort of `Rc<RefCell>` pointing to one of the values in a node, as to avoid this sort of dependency chain? I really am stumped as to what to do.

Please do not suggest passing a function to apply to the value with the given name rather than returning a reference, as that does not apply to my use case: I really do need just a mutable reference (or something allowing me to obtain one.)

I do not believe that this is a duplicate of [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap), as that answer only deals with returning a reference to a component of a value contained in a single `RefCell` (which I already do using `RefMut::map`). My problem involves a chain of `Rc<RefCell>`s, which that question does not address.

Comment: Perhaps one of these: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51341643/returning-reference-from-refcell  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30281664/how-do-i-borrow-a-refcellhashmap-find-a-key-and-return-a-reference-to-the-re 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25233925/cant-figure-out-a-function-to-return-a-reference-to-a-given-type-stored-in-refc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return a reference to something inside a RefCell without breaking encapsulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29401626/how-do-i-return-a-reference-to-something-inside-a-refcell-without-breaking-encap)

Comment: I do not believe it is a duplicate: that question involves getting a reference from a single RefCell (which I already use in the code posted with my question), my question involves getting one from a RefCell chain